# For $f(x_1,x_2) = -2x_1^2 - (x_2 -1)^2$, is $v=(4,1)$ a direction of increase or decrease at $x=(0,1)$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

First of all thanks for your patience and for helping me out!

So I am facing the following exercise:

Consider the function $f(x_1,x_2) = -2x_1^2 - (x_2 -1)^2$ . Say if $ v = (4,1)$ is a direction of increase or of decrease of $f$ in $ x= (0,1)$.

So first of all I calculated the gradient:

$$ \bigtriangledown f(x_1,x_2) = ( -4x_1, -2x_2 +2) $$

Then I plugged the point $x = (0,1)$ in the gradient.

I so obtain

$$ (0, 0) $$

What is this supposed to mean? Am I supposed to take further steps?

As always, thanks for the help!

Comment: The gradient of the function you've written is in fact $\langle -\color{red}{2}, -2x_2+2\rangle$. Where do you get $-4x_1$?

Comment: My Bad! I forgot a ^2 in the text! Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

You’ve found a critical point of the function. The hessian at this point is $\operatorname{diag}(-4,-2)$. Both eigenvalues of this matrix are negative, so this point is a local maximum: the function decreases in *every* direction here.